# How to generate an Id using DataImportHandler?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I'm new in Solr and I'm struggling to import some XML Data which does not contain a ID field, although It's required as it says my schema.xml:

An XML example:

```
<results>
<estacions>
<estacio id="72400" nom="Aeroport"/>
<estacio id="79600" nom="Arenys de Mar"/>
...
</estacions>
</results>
```

Schema.xml:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

At this point, I need to import this xml from http fetch, then I use DataimportHandler.
This is my data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
            <entity name="renfe"                        
                    url="http://host_url/myexample.xml"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    forEach="/results/estacions/estacio"
                    transformer="script:generateCustomId">
                    <field column="idestacio"   xpath="/results/estacions/estacio/@id" commonField="true" />
                    <field column="nomestacio"  xpath="/results/estacions/estacio/@nom" commonField="true" />
            </entity>
    </document>
```

Then, it seems to work properly, but I got the following error:
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: id

This makes me think that I should generate an automatic id while importing, and by using the data-config.xml, but I don't reach to see how to do it.

How should I do? Using a ScriptTransformer? Any idea is grateful

And another question: Can I force a value during the import ?

For ex: `<field column="site"  value="estacions"/>` (obviously this does not work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use code below to generate ID:

```
<dataConfig>
  <script><![CDATA[
        id = 1;
        function GenerateId(row) {
            row.put('id', (id ++).toFixed());
            return row;
        }
       ]]></script>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
            <entity name="renfe"                        
                    url="http://host_url/myexample.xml"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    forEach="/results/estacions/estacio"
                    transformer="script:GenerateId">
                    <field column="idestacio"   xpath="/results/estacions/estacio/@id" commonField="true" />
                    <field column="nomestacio"  xpath="/results/estacions/estacio/@nom" commonField="true" />
            </entity>
    </document>
```